# extensionless image file not visible in IIS7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

We have extension less images which worked perfectly in iis6. However, in IIS7.5 even after adding the static file handler i am not able to get it to display the image. I have ticked the Static content option in properties for IIS7.5 the operating system for server is Windows Server 2008 R2. The image file with extension are visible properly. However those without extension give me 404 in fiddler. The mime type application/octet-stream has also been added for .* filename extension

Comment: why the negative marking guys?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer myself. We need to have the Static File Module above the ExtensionlessUrlHandler. 
 
  [image]

This worked and now i am able to see my extensionless images as well.

Comment: I assume this is in IIS Manager on the Handler Mappings view for the website?