# Extensionless temp image in an asp.net mvc app and proper IIS mappings

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

In a mvc application there is a need to save images in a temp folder. When the image path resolves in a html document I get a message about mime mapping. The temp files are being saved as Temp\b824cc4f-c929-4e8e-9bfd-9a2f332589(No extension).

I found a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473632/extensionless-image-file-not-visible-in-iis7-5) but it seems to add another requirement for deployment. The relevant app config section is below:

```
<handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
 </handlers>
```

What is the best way to handle this in the application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding '*'(image/png) mime type to the temp directory. I would rather have this in the app web config as opposed to turning this into a deployment requirement.

[image: Mime Types]